# Why have two functions for operator overload?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, pass-by-reference

I'm currently writing a double linked list using dynamic memory in C++ for one of my classes. I've already got the code written, I just had a question.

Our professor required us to write both an

```
int& operator[](int position)
```

AND an

```
int operator[](int position) const
```

function.

What was the point in doing two functions for the same operator? I'm sure there's some kind of logic behind it, haha. Is it just so I can do a = arr[i] and also do arr[i] = a?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The `const` variant is for reading, e.g. when you assign a value to a variable. The compiler will give you an error when trying to modify the list value at the specified index. Example for const is `a = arr[i]` as you wrote.

2) The `non-const variant` is usually used when you actually set the value at the certain index of the list. Although you could use this variant for getting a value as well. However, then the compiler would not raise an error when your intention is to just read and your code would accidentally write. That could lead to subtle bugs which you can avoid by using `const` for such cases. Example for non-const is `arr[i] = a` as you wrote.

If you have both versions present, the non-const version version will be called for reading when you execute the indexing on a non-const object.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a `const` list object, you should only be able to read values from it. If you have a modifiable one, you should be able to both read and write values. The first is done with the `const` version, which will be called for a `const` object.

Comment: But since the capability of the const function is also covered in the other function, why bother writing it? Is it just to have the safety of the compiler yelling at you if your code alters the data?

Comment: @user2816987 It’s *not* covered by the non-`const` variant, because that cannot be called on a `const` object.

Comment: @user2816987: I tried to explain in my answer why bother. Is that unclear?

Comment: @LaszloPapp - you can have a `const` object of that list type, and if you do, the compiler won't let you call the non-`const` member function on that object. One important aspect of C++ programming is const-correctness: functions that shouldn't modify an object shouldn't be able to. So a function that only looks at the contents of an `array` object should take that object by `const` reference e.g., `void show(const list&)`. You can call that object with a modifiable `list` object; the compiler won't let the function modify the object. That's a good thing: it's easier to find incorrect changes.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve with this post.

Comment: @LaszloPapp - you asked "why bother". I told you. Const correctness.

Answer (score 1):

When your object is const, you can only use the `const` version of the operator, which by virtue of being const doesn't allow modification of your object or returning non-cons pointers/references to internal members. So when your object is non-const you need a non-const operator that allows modifications so you can write `foo[i]=n`

Answer (score 0):

> Is it just so I can do `a = arr[i]` and also do `arr[i] = a`?

Yes, that's what it's for.

- if you have a `const` or a non-`const` list then you can perform the `a = arr[i]` assignment;
- the version of the operator that returns an `int&` is so that you can perform `arr[i] = a`, which of course requires a non-`const` list.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - no, it won't compile. You can't assign to the result of `arr[i]` if `operator[]` returns int.

Comment: @PeteBecker: No, it can't. `struct T { int operator[](int) { return 3; } }; int main() { T t; t[5] = 2; }` => `error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment`

Comment: @PeteBecker: Right, so first you claim it can be done, and now you admit that it can't. What are you trying to say?

Comment: @PeteBecker: Ah, apply `s/can/can't/` to your first comment and you're pointing out a flaw in my answer. Spotted it now. Thanks!

Comment: The non-`const` version returns `int&`, so it's okay to assign to the result. The `const` version returns `int`, and you can't assign to that result.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Yes, I know — I just demonstrated that a few comments up!

Answer (score 0):

Its just if you have a const variable of your object, lets call it `A const a;` then you are only allowed to call const functions, like your const overload of `operator [] (...) const`, which only provides reading. You are not allowed to call the non const `operator [] (...)` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Where you have a doubly-linked list object that is defined with the `const` qualifier (commonly called "a const object") or referred to via a pointer-to-const or a reference-to-const, you want to be enable reading but not writing. The `const`-qualified operator does that.

Where you have an object that is defined without the `const` qualifier, or referred to via a pointer-to-non-const or a reference-to-non-const, you want to enable both reading and writing. The non-`const`-qualified operator does that.

So, the reason you bother writing two overloads is to implement both behaviours.

If you only wanted reading, regardless of constness, then you would only write the `const` version because `const`-qualified member functions can be used to interact with both cases, whereas non-`const`-qualified member functions can only be used on the names of non-`const`-qualified objects (or via a pointer-to-non-const or a reference-to-non-const).

If you only wanted `operator[]` to apply to non-`const` objects then you would only write the non-`const`-qualified version. This might seem strange, since you don't expect `operator[]` to need the object to be modifiable, but as it happens this is exactly what `std::map` does with `operator[]`.